# Unable to use conditional validation rules - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am binding directly to the model property. I am unable to submit the form as there are two forms in a single livewire component. 1st form is to edit the user, which consist of `name`, `email`, `role`, and the 2nd form is to invite the user, which consist of `email`.

I am unable to submit the form as I have combinedly stated the rules for both the forms under the rules protected property. So when ever I try to edit a user, using the first form, It checks for `email` field as well, which is present in the invitation form. How can I make it work in this structure.

- App\Http\Livewire\UserController.php

```
public $showUserManagementModal = false;
public $showUserInvitationModal = false;

public User $user;
public Invitation $invitation;

protected function rules() {
    if ($showUserManagementModal = true)
        return [
            'user.name' => 'required | string | max:255',
            'user.email' => 'required | string | email | max:255',
            'role' => 'required',
        ];

    if ($showUserInvitationModal = true)
        return [
            'invitation.email' => 'required | string | email | max:255 | unique:invitations,email',
        ];
}

public function createInvitation() {
    $this -> useCachedRows();

    $this -> resetValidation();
    $this -> invitation = new Invitation();
    $this -> showUserInvitationModal = true;
}

public function saveInvitation() {
    $this -> validate();
    $this -> invitation -> generateInvitationToken();
    $this -> invitation -> save();
    $this -> showUserInvitationModal = false;
}

public function manageUser(User $user) {
    $this -> useCachedRows();

    $this -> resetValidation();
    $this -> user = $user;
    $this -> role = $user -> roles -> pluck('id');
    $this -> showUserManagementModal = true;
}

public function saveUser() {
    $this -> validate();
    $this -> validate([
        'user.email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$this -> user -> id,
    ]);
    $this -> user -> roles() -> sync($this -> role);
    $this -> user -> save();
    $this -> showUserManagementModal = false;

    $this -> dispatchBrowserEvent('notify', $this -> user -> name.' Updated Successfully');
}
```

Comment: You need to add some extra fields on your edit form. So, when you submit that form - check these fields are exists then don't check the validation or whatever you don't want to execute on your save function.

Comment: @Tuhin How should I proceed with it, can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Before trying to build an app with Laravel, you may want to take a step back and learn the basics of PHP first. Just looking at the first line of your `rules()` method, you are assigning a value of `true` to the variable `$showUserManagementModal`. If you wanted to do a comparison, that's a different operator and it would fail because you haven't defined the variable anywhere. You also aren't using that method anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for throwing some light on it @miken32, I have already declared it as false by default. How can I further make the validation to exclude the field if I am editing a user and exclude the other three fields when I am creating an invite.

Comment: And I am changing the state of the `$showUserManagementModal` from false to true, when ever an admin tries to manage a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your `rules()` method - one being that you are checking for a local variable (its not checking a property of the class) and secondly you're assigning values to the variable instead of comparing (single `=` instead of double `==`).

```php
protected function rules() {
    if ($this->showUserManagementModal === true)
        return [
            'user.name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'user.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'role' => 'required',
        ];

    if ($this->showUserInvitationModal === true)
        return [
            'invitation.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:invitations,email',
        ];
}
```

You should also move the unique-check for the email to the `rules()` method instead of checking that explicitly in your `saveUser()` method.

```php
protected function rules() {
    if ($this->showUserManagementModal === true)
        return [
            'user.name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'user.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email'.($this->user->id ? ','.$this->user->id : ''),
            'role' => 'required',
        ];

    if ($this->showUserInvitationModal === true)
        return [
            'invitation.email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:invitations,email',
        ];
}
```

Comment: Its working perfectly, its just when I try to shift the unique-check for the email to the rules() I get the following error, `Typed property App\Http\Livewire\Backend\UserManagement\UserController::$user must not be accessed before initialization`